# where does snap store user data for apps that have been removed

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I've uninstalled a snap app using "ubuntu softwares" and it removed all my relevant user data from /home/$USER/snap/appname as I've heard snap makes a snapshot of this data before removing it. Since the app we're talking about is no longer available as a snap, reinstalling it is not an option. So having said all that, where do I find the snapshot of my userdata snappy made? Thank you for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you uninstall a snap, a snapshot that contains a copy of your user, system and configuration data is automatically created, and will be retained for 31 days before being automatically removed. This data is stored in a zip file under the directory **`/var/lib/snapd/snapshots`.**

Use the `snap saved` command to list saved snapshots. The first column indicates the ID of the snapshot. All snaps for which a snapshot was taken on a specific time will share the same ID. The "auto" annotation in the last column of the output indicates that the snapshot was automatically created. You can restore a snapshot with `snap restore ID`.

See the documentation for [more information on snapshots](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapshots).

Comment: I didn't mention the restore part because the snap no longer exists, according to OP. But, otherwise, for existing snaps, restore definitely would help.

Comment: @DKBose on deleting a snap, a snapshot is automatically created and kept for 31 days, so can be restored within that period even if the snap is gone

Comment: What I don't know / did not know is whether restore works even if the snap no longer exists. That a snapshot is saved is clear (unless --purge is used).

Comment: Yes it does. It places the files back under ~/snap/appname, even if the app itself is not anymore installed (and even if ~/snap/appname was removed)