# How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, firefox, snap, ppa

As far as I see in the ongoing development for **22.04 Jammy**, **Firefox** is a Snap package.
The related Deb package in apt is just a shortcut/link to the that snap version.

I prefer my installation not to be from snap packages, since I find them too much 'Ubuntu-specific'.

Are there alternative ways to install Firefox on Jammy?
My favourite option would be an *Apt repository* or *PPA*. I will test the **Flatpak** version with my test virtual machine in the meantime.

Comment: There is an **Ubuntu bug here for permission problems caused by Snap packaged Firefox**: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1972762 . **Please go mark that bug as "also affects me"** if you're having permission problems in Firefox due it being managed by Snap.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you switch to the APT version, **you will lose the bookmarks in the snap version unless you sync them with your Firefox account, or export them manually**.

---

The [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403204/124466) by Organic Marble is for Firefox-ESR, and the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403107/124466) by eddygeek is for the beta version.

This answer is for the **latest stable** version of Firefox. You can use the [Firefox PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) maintained by Mozilla team.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

Then, copy and paste the following code in a terminal in one go (don't copy-paste line by line) to prioritize the apt version of firefox over the snap version.

```
echo '
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: firefox
Pin: version 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: -1
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
```

Next, remove the snap version of firefox

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

If you see the following error,

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove data for snap "firefox" (1943) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_ZA.dic: read-only file system)
```

Then run the following commands ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1434769/124466)) to disable the hunspell service, and try removing Firefox snap once again.

```
sudo systemctl stop var-snap-firefox-common-host\\x2dhunspell.mount
sudo systemctl disable var-snap-firefox-common-host\\x2dhunspell.mount
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Install Firefox with apt.

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

To ensure that unattended upgrades do not reinstall the snap version of Firefox, enter the following command. Alternatively, you can [turn off](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/02/how-to-disable-automatic-update-ubuntu) unattended upgrades.

```
echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
```

---

### To undo these changes

1. Remove the firefox PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

2. Remove the apt pin.

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
```

3. Remove the apt version and reinstall snap.

```
sudo apt remove firefox && sudo snap install firefox
```

Source: [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: It is stupid that Ubuntu thinks that the version in snap is newer than the one from the actual repository.  This answer makes sense to block Ubuntu from installing the snap version but it really seems like a pain that you have to add the pinning to block it now where in the past you did not.  Thanks for a great answer!  +1

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. As a developer, I won't tolerate `curl localhost:3000/` working fine, but the browser barfing some BS error at me on that same URL due to Snap shenanigans.

Comment: Beware of two things if doing this:
a) the snap has put your firefox profile in `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/...` (though an old one _may_ be in `~/.mozilla/firefox/...`)
b) that directory (`~/snap/firefox/common/`) will be removed(!) when you remove the snap

You probably therefore want to backup/move your firefox profile before doing this.

If you get caught out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245136/where-does-snap-store-user-data-for-apps-that-have-been-removed and https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapshots may help you get your profile back.

Comment: Won't this answer erase your profile and all your app data - bookmarks, history, settings, passwords, etc?

Comment: @markling Yes it will, but you can sync everything by signing into Firefox

Comment: So it is necessary to sign up and deploy Firefox Sync before doing this operation or you will lose your data? Hadn't you better say that?

Comment: @markling Is not that obvious, given snap is self contained?

Answer (score 11):

**Warning - answer may have been obsoleted by recent events as of Feb  2024**

You can install the official Firefox ESR (Extended Support Release) version via .deb from the Mozilla ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
sudo apt install firefox-esr
```

More information is available here: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/03/install-firefox-esr-ubuntu/

Comment: Note that if you try to use your old FireFox profile with FireFox ESR, it will fail to startup and complain about possible profile corruption. I didn't try to find a work around, I just switched the PPA install of regular Firefox from the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/56280).

Comment: You can keep your profile, but only if the ESR version is the same as (or newer) than the current release version. And this only happens once a year.

Comment: The ESR version worked for me!! Thank you.

Comment: @user535733 thanks, done

Comment: Could you explain why this may have been obsoleted? What recent events are you referring to?

Comment: @FWDekker there's now an official Mozilla ppa for the regular version of FF, more frequently updated than the ESR version. https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/04/install-firefox-deb-ubuntu-22-04/

Answer (score 10):

This was the only thing that worked for me after **upgrading to Ubuntu 22.10.**

First, remove the Snap version of Firefox:

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

(If you have settings in the Snap version of Firefox under `~/snap/firefox/`, you may want to migrate those to `~/.mozilla/firefox/`)

Then add [the PPA from mozillateam](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

Now, the package `firefox` is provided by both the Ubuntu repos and the Mozilla PPA. The version provided in the Ubuntu repos is a transitional package that actually installs the Snap version of Firefox behind the scenes, which in this case, we don't want. Check that you can see both `firefox` packages by running:

```
apt info -a firefox
```

To prevent the installation of the Snap version of Firefox through the `firefox` package provided by Ubuntu, we need to modify this file as root, using `gnome-text-editor` or whichever text editor you prefer:

```
sudo gnome-text-editor /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozillafirefoxppa
```

Add these lines:

```
Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 501

Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: -1
```

The first three lines give priority to the `firefox` packages provided by the Mozilla PPA. And the last three lines disable installing the `firefox` packages from Ubuntu's repositories.

Run `sudo apt update` to make sure the changes have been taken into account.

Now, you should be able to install the PPA version of Firefox. You can simulate an installation of Firefox using `--dry-run`, like this, so as to check which version of Firefox will be installed:

```
sudo apt install --verbose-versions --dry-run firefox
```

If you don't see the word `snap` in the version number of the `firefox` package (for example: `1:1snap1-0ubuntu2`), you are good to go. Run this command to install Firefox (without Snap):

```
sudo apt install --verbose-versions firefox
```

Comment: My reference: https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/

Comment: Remember to undo this before upgrading to the next version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Why undo this before to upgrading Ubuntu?

Comment: @E.l4d3 I upgrade Ubuntu without undoing this, and it caused problems with APT. Specifically, the pinning caused problems. I can't recall much more than that, now.

Answer (score 6):

The transition of Firefox from Deb to Snap was announced in September 2021. See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/feature-freeze-exception-seeding-the-official-firefox-snap-in-ubuntu-desktop/24210/199 for complete discussion.

> This is the result of cooperation and collaboration between the Desktop and Snap teams at Canonical and Mozilla developers, and is the first step towards a deb-to-snap transition that will take place during the 22.04 development cycle.

Translation: The shift of Firefox from Deb to Snap is a Mozilla-driven decision. The Ubuntu teams are trying to make the transition as painless as possible for most folks.

A lot of volunteers have been testing the Firefox Snap, discovering/filing/fixing bugs since the 21.10 cycle to sand down the rough edges and  document the corner-cases. (It's been my daily driver since then)

Folks who want Firefox have several options:

1. Use the Snap. The Snap comes from Mozilla upstream, and is designed to be cross-distro and cross-platform. You should not find it "Ubuntu-specific." The Firefox Snap will be included in stock installs of Ubuntu Desktop.
2. Download the binary from Mozilla upstream. This requires knowledge of how to install and uninstall without a package manager. It's the same binary used in the Snap.
3. If you still want to use deb packages that are in the Ubuntu Repositories, then join Debian and help the volunteer packagers who work Firefox. It's a complex beast to packages as a deb (which is why Mozilla is unenthusiatic about continuing the effort) but the community --with enough volunteers-- is capable of great things.
4. Add the [Mozilla deb repository](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux#w_install-firefox-deb-package-for-debian-based-distributions). Use apt-pinning to select this repository instead of the Ubuntu repos.
5. Flatpak and other add-on package managers.

Comment: Both Flatpak or Snap have the same problem. Both are methods of packaging something "non-native" to the system that brings a lot of environment/dependencies/etc. with it. While for some "standalone" applications this is OK, such an important piece of system as a default web browser should be closely integrated with the system, which means it should be a .deb package. Use of Debian .deb package seems to be the only viable way.

Comment: @raj well, it's not going to be a .deb package anymore, like it or not, without a lot more volunteer participation.

Comment: Somebody will provide PPA with firefox.deb soon enough

Comment: The Mozilla Team PPA has already made the package (along with ESR & thunderbird). The maintainer of Ubuntu's own Firefox package is the team member. https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa. And there's a [step by step guide](https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/) to add the PPA and set priority.

Comment: This bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1661935 (Snap does not support NativeMessaging) makes the snap version too limited for now (eg. browserpass extension, kde plasma integration, gnome extensions integration, etc...). It is a real regression, and I'm not sure the proposed solution will be ready soon...

Comment: So what exactly happens if you've deliberately purged the firefox snap from 21.10 and installed the non-snap version?  Is it going to dishonor your purge and install the snap anyway, or not install Firefox at all?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned before

Remove snap version of the firefox

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Add mozillateam repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

Unattended updates

```
echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
```

If you don't want to update all packages from LP-PPA-mozillateam then i would
do following:

```
echo '
Package: firefox
Pin: version 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 99

Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 99

Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
```

This makes only firefox package updated from LP-PPA-mozillateam, and not others. Also reduce priority of the firefox snap version.

And now you are ready to install firefox

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the following workaround to get a deb-based firefox from the [firefox-next](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next) ppa.

Warning: It is the beta version!

Because the package name is also `firefox`, we need to [blacklist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835361/blacklist-only-one-specific-version-of-a-package-for-upgrades) the dummy snap shortcut package which has version 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2

```
sudo apt remove firefox
echo "
Package: firefox
Pin: version 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2
Pin-Priority: 99
" | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
sudo apt install firefox
```

Here is a variant of the `add-apt-repository` step, that still respects the new package signing requirements - it works with both *ppa* (main release) and *firefox-next* (beta) repositories:

```sh
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/firefox.gpg --recv-keys 9BDB3D89CE49EC21
echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/firefox.gpg]  https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy main 
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/firefox.list
```

(This was useful for me because under pre-release of KDE Neon 22.04, `add-apt-repository` currently returns *aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Neon/jammy*)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the latest official .deb builds working with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy) here:
[https://launchpad.net/~phd/+archive/ubuntu/firefox/](https://launchpad.net/%7Ephd/+archive/ubuntu/firefox/)

This is a PPA repository with official Ubuntu packages released originally for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal) and updated automatically as soon as a new version is released.

Answer (score 0):

The switch from a snap Firefox installation to a ppa and apt installation is  is automated [here](https://github.com/TruCol/Self-host-GitLab-CI-for-GitHub/blob/develop/src/prerequisites/firefox_version.sh), with an attempt at a bit more control and documentation than [the effective and compact script by Archisman Panigrahi](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/846880). Perhaps someone likes it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# This script verifies Firefox is installed in the right way. Firefox is used
# to set the GitHub SSH keys and GitHub personal access tokens automatically.
# And to control a Firefox browser, it needs to be installed using apt instead
# of snap. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72405117
# https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/

# Run with:
# bash -c "src/prerequisites/firefox_version.sh"

command_output_contains(){
    local substring="$1"
    shift
    local command_output="$@"
    if grep -q "$substring" <<< "$command_output"; then
        echo "FOUND"
    else
        echo "NOTFOUND"
    fi
}

#######################################
# Checks if firefox is installed using snap or not.
# Locals:
#  respones_lines
#  found_firefox
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If command was evaluated successfully.
# Outputs:
#  FOUND if firefox is installed using snap.
#  NOTFOUND if firefox is not installed using snap.
#######################################
firefox_via_snap(){
    local respons_lines="$(snap list)"
    local found_firefox=$(command_output_contains "firefox" "${respons_lines}")
    echo $found_firefox
}

#######################################
# Checks if firefox is installed using ppa and apt or not.
# Locals:
#  respones_lines
#  found_firefox
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If command was evaluated successfully.
# Outputs:
#  FOUND if firefox is installed using ppa and apt.
#  NOTFOUND if firefox is not installed using ppa and apt.
#######################################
firefox_via_apt(){
    local respons_lines="$(apt list --installed)"
    local found_firefox=$(command_output_contains "firefox" "${respons_lines}")
    echo $found_firefox
}

#######################################
# Checks if firefox is added as ppa or not.
# Locals:
#  respones_lines
#  ppa_indicator
#  found_firefox_ppa
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If command was evaluated successfully.
# Outputs:
#  FOUND if firefox is added as ppa.
#  NOTFOUND if firefox is not added as ppa.
#######################################
firefox_ppa_is_added(){
    # Get list of ppa packages added for apt usage.
    local respons_lines="$(apt policy)"
    # Specify identifier for firefox ppa presence.
    local ppa_indicator="https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu"
    local found_firefox_ppa=$(command_output_contains "$ppa_indicator" "${respons_lines}")
    echo $found_firefox_ppa
}


#######################################
# Remove Firefox if it is installed using snap.
# Locals:
#  respones_lines
#  found_firefox
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If command was evaluated successfully.
# Outputs:
#  FOUND if firefox is installed using snap.
#  NOTFOUND if firefox is not installed using snap.
#######################################
remove_snap_install_firefox_if_existant(){
    if [ "$(firefox_via_snap)" == "FOUND" ]; then
        
        # Prompt user for permission.
        ask_user_swapping_firefox_install_is_ok
        
        # User permission is granted here, remove firefox snap installation.
        yes | sudo snap remove firefox 2>&1
        assert_firefox_is_not_installed_using_snap
        echo "Firefox is removed." > /dev/tty
    fi
    assert_firefox_is_not_installed_using_snap
}

#######################################
# Ask user for permission to swap out Firefox installation.
# Locals:
#  yn
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If command was evaluated successfully.
#  3 If the user terminates the program.
# Outputs:
#  Mesage indicating Firefox will be uninstalled.
#######################################
ask_user_swapping_firefox_install_is_ok(){
    echo "" > /dev/tty
    echo "Hi, firefox is installed using snap. To automatically add your " > /dev/tty
    echo "access tokens to GitHub, we need to control the firefox browser." > /dev/tty
    echo "To control the firefox browser, we need to switch the installation" > /dev/tty
    echo "method from snap to apt." > /dev/tty
    echo "" > /dev/tty
    echo "We will not preserve your bookmarks, history and extensions." > /dev/tty
    echo "" > /dev/tty
    while true; do
        read -p "May we proceed? (y/n)? " yn
        case $yn in
            [Yy]* ) echo "Removing Firefox, please wait 5 minutes, we will tell you when it is done."; break;;
            [Nn]* ) echo "Installation terminated by user."; exit 3;;
            * ) echo "Please answer yes or no." > /dev/tty;;
        esac
    done
}

#######################################
# Asserts Firefox is not installed using snap, throws an error otherwise.
# Locals:
#  None
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If Firefox is not installed using snap.
#  1 If Firefox is still isntalled using snap.
# Outputs:
#  Nothing
#######################################
# Run with:
assert_firefox_is_not_installed_using_snap(){
    if [ "$(firefox_via_snap)" == "FOUND" ]; then
        echo "Error, Firefox installation was still installed using snap." > /dev/tty
        exit 2
    fi
}
assert_firefox_is_installed_using_ppa(){
    if [ "$(firefox_via_apt)" != "FOUND" ]; then
        echo "Error, Firefox installation was not performed using ppa and apt." > /dev/tty
        exit 2
    fi
}

#######################################
# Asserts Firefox ppa is added to apt.
# Locals:
#  None
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If Firefox ppa is added to apt.
#  4 Otherwise.
# Outputs:
#  Error message indicating firefox ppa is not added correctly.
#######################################
# Run with:
assert_firefox_ppa_is_added_to_apt(){
    if [ "$(firefox_ppa_is_added)" == "NOTFOUND" ]; then
        echo "Error, Firefox ppa was not added to apt." > /dev/tty
        exit 4
    fi
}
assert_firefox_ppa_is_removed_from_apt(){
    if [ "$(firefox_ppa_is_added)" == "FOUND" ]; then
        echo "Error, Firefox ppa was not removed from apt." > /dev/tty
        exit 4
    fi
}

#######################################
# Adds firefox ppa to install using apt if it is not added yet.
# Locals:
#  None
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If Firefox is not installed using snap.
#  1 If Firefox is still isntalled using snap.
# Outputs:
#  Nothing
#######################################
add_firefox_ppa_if_not_in_yet(){
    if [ "$(firefox_ppa_is_added)" == "NOTFOUND" ]; then
        echo "Now adding Firefox ppa to apt." > /dev/tty
        echo "" > /dev/tty
        yes | sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
    fi
    assert_firefox_ppa_is_added_to_apt
}
remove_firefox_ppa(){
    if [ "$(firefox_ppa_is_added)" == "FOUND" ]; then
        echo "Now removing Firefox ppa to apt." > /dev/tty
        echo "" > /dev/tty
        yes | sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mozillateam/ppa
    fi
    assert_firefox_ppa_is_removed_from_apt
}


#######################################
# Asserts the Firefox installation package preference is set to ppa/apt. Does
# this by verifying the file content is as expected using hardcoded MD5Sum.
# Locals:
#  None
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If Firefox is not installed using snap.
#  1 If Firefox is still isntalled using snap.
# Outputs:
#  Nothing
#######################################
assert_firefox_installation_package_preference_file_content(){
    local preferences_path="$1"
    local md5_output=$(md5sum $preferences_path)
    local expected_md5_output="961023613b10ce4ae8150f78d698a53e  $preferences_path"
    if [ "$md5_output" != "$expected_md5_output" ]; then
        echo "Error, the md5 output of: $preferences_path is not as expected." > /dev/tty
        echo "md5_output=         $md5_output" > /dev/tty
        echo "expected_md5_output=$expected_md5_output" > /dev/tty
        exit 5
    fi
}

assert_firefox_auto_update_file_content(){
    local preferences_path="$1"
    local md5_output=$(md5sum $preferences_path)
    local expected_md5_output="ffd6e239ef98a236741f4ba5c84ab20e  $preferences_path"
    if [ "$md5_output" != "$expected_md5_output" ]; then
        echo "Error, the md5 output of: $preferences_path is not as expected." > /dev/tty
        echo "md5_output=         $md5_output" > /dev/tty
        echo "expected_md5_output=$expected_md5_output" > /dev/tty
        exit 5
    fi
}


#######################################
# Sets the Firefox installation package preference from snap to ppa/apt.
# Locals:
#  preferences_path
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If Firefox is not installed using snap.
#  1 If Firefox is still isntalled using snap.
# Outputs:
#  Nothing
#######################################
# Run with:
change_firefox_package_priority(){
    local preferences_path="/etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox"

    # Set the installation package preference in firefox.
    echo 'Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001' | sudo tee "$preferences_path"

    # Verify the installation package preference is set correctly in firefox.
    assert_firefox_installation_package_preference_file_content "$preferences_path"
}

#######################################
# Ensures the firefox installation is updated automatically.
# Locals:
#  update_filepath
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If Firefox is not installed using snap.
#  1 If Firefox is still isntalled using snap.
# Outputs:
#  Nothing
#######################################
ensure_firefox_is_updated_automatically(){
    local update_filepath="/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox"
    # Set the installation package preference in firefox.
    echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee "$update_filepath"

    # Verify the installation package preference is set correctly in firefox.
    assert_firefox_auto_update_file_content "$update_filepath"
}


#######################################
# Installs firefox using ppa and apt.
# Locals:
#  None
# Globals:
#  None
# Arguments:
#  None
# Returns:
#  0 If Firefox is installed using ppa and apt.
#  1 If Firefox is mpt installed using ppa and apt.
# Outputs:
#  Nothing
#######################################
install_firefox_using_ppa(){
    if [ "$(firefox_via_apt)" == "NOTFOUND" ]; then
        yes | sudo apt install firefox 2>&1
    fi
    assert_firefox_is_installed_using_ppa
    echo "Firefox is installed succesfully using ppa and apt." > /dev/tty
}


# Swap Firefox installation from snap to ppa/apt using functions above.
# 0. Detect how firefox is installed.
# 1. If firefox installed with snap:
# 1.a Ask user for permission to swap out Firefox installation.
# 1.b. Verify and mention the bookmarks, addons and history are not removed.
# 1.c Remove snap firefox if it exists.
# 1.d Verify snap firefox is removed.
remove_snap_install_firefox_if_existant

# 2.a Add firefox ppa to apt if not yet in.
# 2.b Verify firefox ppa is added (successfully).
add_firefox_ppa_if_not_in_yet
#remove_firefox_ppa

# 3.a Change Firefox package priority to ensure it is installed from PPA/deb/apt
# instead of snap.
# 3.b Verify Firefox installation priority was set correctly.
change_firefox_package_priority

# 4.a Ensure the Firefox installation is automatically updated.
# 4.b Verify the auto update command is completed succesfully.
ensure_firefox_is_updated_automatically

# 5.a Install Firefox using apt.
# 5.v Verify firefox is installed succesfully, and only once, using apt/PPA.
install_firefox_using_ppa
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to others but I ran into a problem with hunspell.  I could not continue without unmounting it.  Like markling and Archisman Panigrahi said, you must back up your Firefox profile somehow, or save it all to the cloud with Firefox Sync, before you begin, or you will lose your bookmarks, passwords, etc.  After making my backup, here is what I did:

```
sudo snap disable firefox
sudo umount /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
sudo snap remove --purge firefox
sudo apt purge firefox
sudo apt autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
echo '
Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 501
   
Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: -1
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/99mozillateamppa
echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firefox
```

The Mozillateam PPA's "firefox" package distributes what is officially a beta version (I received Firefox 116 exactly one week before it will be officially released), although you can think of it as a release candidate (116 had already been in beta for three weeks before it was packaged for the Mozillateam PPA).  If you're not completely comfortable with that, then you can edit the last line and install "firefox-esr" instead of "firefox":

```
sudo apt install firefox-esr
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently the FF team presented an official Debian [repo with Firefox Nightly](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2023/10/30/introducing-mozillas-firefox-nightly-deb-packages-for-debian-based-linux-distributions/)

```
# make folder for PGP repo key
sudo install -d -m 0755 /etc/apt/keyrings
# download repo key and store to /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -q https://packages.mozilla.org/apt/repo-signing-key.gpg -O /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc
# add the APT repository to sources list
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc] https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla.list > /dev/null

# Update package list
sudo apt-get update
# Install the Firefox Nightly .deb package
sudo apt-get install firefox-nightly
```

The command to start FF Nightly is `firefox-nightly`. It's blue icon will be shown alongside of FF.
It will be updated more often than snap version which may be anoying.